# what is difference between XXX and java.lang.Class<XXX>

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm building a test application in android, and want to mock the component. 
but I got an exception

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method XXX.inject argument 1 has type XXX, 
got java.lang.Class<XXX>
```

So they cannot be used as the same type?

Comment: yes,they can't be used as the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. They are not the same thing or the same type. `Class<XXX>` is the same as `XXX.class`, that is

```
Class<String> cls = String.class;
System.out.println(cls.getName());
```

Outputs

```
java.lang.String
```